# strangely lost string value

Tags: vba, excel

It is definitely a newbie question but really make me very frustrated. I cannot figure out at all why I would lost the value after assigning the value to one variable. Strange thing is there is no problem in displaying the cell_location but the cell_locaton1 becomes null in the message box.

```
Sub COPYCELL()
    Dim bottomCell As Range
    Dim offsetCell As Range
    Dim cell_location As String
    Dim cell_location1 As String
    Dim SC As String

    With ActiveSheet
        Set bottomCell = .Cells.Find(what:="XXX")
        Set offsetCell = .Cells.Find(what:="YYY")
        cell_location = "A" & bottomCell.Row
        cell_locaton1 = "A" & offsetCell.Row

        SC = cell_location & ":" & cell_location1
        MsgBox SC

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The best answer to this question is two words: `Option Explicit`. Try it :)

Comment: There is a typo in  cell_locaton1 = "A" & offsetCell.Row

Answer (score 1):

Typo? Missing i from the bottom statement.

```
Dim cell_location1 As String

cell_locaton1 = "A" & offsetCell.Row
```

Comment: Yes. I am an idiot. Thanks! I have been stuck with it for hours.

Comment: @pau that's unfortunate, because typing option explicit would have costed you barely a few seconds, or a few minutes more for declaring the variables.